# Get text value of JSON key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string

I have this json data, stored in a jquery variable "`jsondata`":

```
var jsondata = {
  "Name": {
    "Jaken": {},
    "Test": {},
    "Hello": {}
  },
  "Date": {
    "Today": {},
    "Tomorrow": {},
    "Wednesday": {}
  },
  "Description": {
    "Me": {},
    "Tester": {},
    "World": {}
  },
    "Another": {
      "Test": {},
      "Test2": {}
  }
};
```

I'm trying to find out how to get the word "Test" as a string.

I've tried `alert(jsondata.Another[1]);`, but that is, understandably, `undefined`. I've tried `alert(value.jsondata.Another[1]);` (Not sure why I thought this would work, but it was worth a shot I guess.

**Is there any documentation that shows how to find the key name of json data in jquery as a string?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use `jQuery`. Use [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var jsondata = {
  "Name": {
    "Jaken": {},
    "Test": {},
    "Hello": {}
  },
  "Date": {
    "Today": {},
    "Tomorrow": {},
    "Wednesday": {}
  },
  "Description": {
    "Me": {},
    "Tester": {},
    "World": {}
  },
  "Another": {
    "Test": {},
    "Test2": {}
  }
};
console.log(Object.keys(jsondata.Another)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the object as an array:

```
Object.keys(jsondata.Another)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually isn't [JSON](http://json.org/), it's an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). The variable you are looking for needs to be accessed by the key, not `1`:

```
alert(jsondata.Another.Test2);
```

As a side note...if you wanted to manipulate JSON, you would use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).